# Through axle to quick release conversions

Tags: quick-release

I have a haibike trekking sduro 4 ebike, I recently bought a new new set of wheels, mistakenly I’ve bought through axle, my bike is quick release, will a conversion kit cure the problem, as I really like the wheels
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it too late to return the wheels as "unsuitable for purpose" ?

Answer (score 2):

Is the only problem that the axle is thru style? Have you confirmed that the dropout width on your new set is identical to your current set. (Probably 100mm front, 142mm rear) ?

Some hub manufacturers (e.g Mavic) design their hubs to use end caps which will convert their through-axle hubs to QR style but that is manufacturer specific and not universal. If that was the case you probably would have been supplied the caps with the wheels.

There are also 3rd party kits that essentially put an axle inside the through axle. A chunk of aluminium rod with milled QR dropout ends, a hole through the middle and maybe an interference element (e.g o-rings) to keep the inner axle tied to the actual axle.

Representative example:
[image]

Assuming the new wheel set is otherwise compatible with your fork and rear dropout combo the adapters should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the hub.

For example, Shimano hubs are either quick release or thru axle. No conversion possible.

However, there are some third party manufacturers that have interchangeable end caps, allowing you to convert a thru axle hub to a quick release hub. However, you have to know what manufacturer has made the hubs, and find the conversion kit available for sale. This may be tricky in many cases. Especially if you bought a complete wheel, the hub manufacturer can be a no-name Chinese manufacturer and finding spare parts may prove impossible.